# Pandas Equivalent to SQL Windows functions with Partition by And Order by

Tags: python, pandas

I wanted to ask what's the most efficient way to replicate SQL window functions using Pandas. For example, I might do in SQL

```
# Example SQL Code
select cumsum(val) over (partition by id order by stuff asc, otherstuff desc)
from df
```

The goal is to write a function like below

```
def window_fun(df, fun, col, partition_by, order_by, asc = None):
    """ 
    equivalent to select fun(col) over 
    (partion by [partition_by] order by [order_by][0] asc[0], ... ,order_by[n] asc[n]) 
    from df
    """
    # fill in function
```

Comment: Check this - https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/window.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a function that should be quite efficient.

```
def window_fun(df, fun, col, partition_by, order_by = None, asc = None):
    """ 
        equivalent to select fun(col) over (partion by [partition_by] order by [order_by]

        df: a pandas DataFrame
        fun: a function that accepts a series as its only input or which can be applied using Series.apply
        x: the column name, as a string, you want to apply fun to
        partition_by: group by keys as a single string or list of strings
        order_by: order by keys as a single string or list of strings
    """

    if type(partition_by) == str:
        partition_by = [partition_by]
    if order_by == None:   
        return df[[col]+partition_by].groupby(partition_by)[col].transform(fun)

    if asc == None:
        asc = [True] * (1 if type(order_by) == str else len(order_by))
    if type(order_by) == str:
        order_by = [order_by]   
    return df[[col]+order_by+partition_by].sort_values(order_by, ascending = asc).groupby(partition_by)[col].transform(fun)
```

Example

```
   df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'id': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'B', 'C'], 
        'val': [1,2,-3,1,5,6,-2], 'stuff':['12','23232','13','1234','3235','3236','732323'], 
         'otherstuff':np.arange(7)})
   print(df)
   window_fun(df,pd.Series.cumsum, 'val', "id", ["stuff", "otherstuff"], [True, False])
```

Comment: Do ```df[[col]+partition_by].sort_values(...``` if you're concerned about copying the whole dataframe. Otherwise your approach is pretty much spot on...

Answer (score 0):

I think, there no need to make custom function.
Use .transform.
Example mean values with partition by ['column1', 'column2']:

```
dataset.groupby(['column1', 'column2'])['values'].transform('mean')
```

Another example.
Cumsum function for column with values, order by date, partition by ['column1', 'column2']:

```
(
    dataset
    .sort_values(by='date')
    .groupby(['column1', 'column2'])['values']
    .transform('cumsum')
)
```